# Data is "stored in a memory" or data is "being stored in a memory"?

Tags: passive-voice

> This memory has data necessary for that program.

I would like to rewrite this such that data is a subject. My example is as follows:

> Data necessary for that program is **being** stored in a memory.

I am unsure whether the "**being**" is necessary.  Is this "being" is necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two sentences do not mean the same thing. Your second sentence can mean that the data is currently **in the process of being stored** into memory (although see also Epanoui's answer for an alternative interpretation of the use of "being"), while your first sentence means that the data is **already stored** in the memory and is currently residing there.

So to answer your question: **no, you don't want to use "being" if you want the two sentences to have exactly the same meaning.**

To rephrase the first sentence with data as the subject you would say:

> The data necessary for that program is stored in this memory.

Answer (score 7):

"Being stored" sounds like the data is stored there now, perhaps temporarily.  If the data is usually stored there, we just say "The data is stored in memory."

Also, "memory" in the computer context is an uncountable noun, so it doesn't need the article "a".

> I want to eat an orange.  I eat a lot of oranges.
>
> I want to drink orange juice.  I drink a lot of orange juice.

Similarly:

> My program stores the data to memory.  It uses a lot of memory.

If you say "a memory", it's usually about one story you remember from the past.

> I have a nice memory of my family visiting France.

This is different from talking about a person's memory in general (this sentences uses both meanings together):

> The memory of my family in France is fading from my memory.

Comment: Good point that I hadn't thought of. I think, to indicate temporary storage, it might be more common to use "being held" rather than "being stored".